# Is it ok to pass data as interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I've found places in my project where an interface been used instead of a class, something like:

```
function test(car: ICar) {
//do something
}

this.test({mark: "Volvo", colour: "red"});
```

Is it ok to follow this practice or should it be rewritten with proper classes?

Comment: TypeScript uses *structural typing*. As long as the object can be shown confirm it 'is a' of that type and is considered type-safe. Thus if ICar (only) requires `mark` and `colour`, the object supplied (which has the type information inferred) is valid; and the question of "should be rewritten [as a class]" is then mostly subjective, although arguments can be made. My advice: write/design code that which will be *less confusing* and *easier to amend* for you - and others - in the future.

Comment: One argument which can be made for a class with proper instantiation, eg, is that - what if a new 'style' (coupe, sedan, hatchback, etc.) property was added? With a class a default value could be used (or be forced in via the constructor); with only structural typing all the objects would need to be updated to conform to the updated ICar - that is, adding to an interface is a *breaking change* when relying only on structural typing. This breaking change is *not necessarily bad* for internal-only types if it is practical/feasible to update the usage sites as the unit compilation will fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object is a perfectly acceptable `ICar` (assuming it's defined as we would infer...).

You don't need to use classes just because you're using TypeScript - they're an orthogonal concept to the type system and can be used only when needed.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer! Though won't this type of code is harder to read, like this.test(new Car(...)) IMO should be easier to read than this.test({...})?
Also I wonder about changes, for instance when I update Car interface, I would have to update all the places where I'm initiating it.

Comment: There's nothing inherently readable about code that uses the `new` keyword. If you've only written in forced-OOP languages before, this can be a bit of a surprise.

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(car: ICar) {
     ...
}
```

is a *function* telling the outside world that it will only accept an object as an argument for the local variable `car` that implements the `ICar` interface.

No interface is passed anywhere.

Think of it as a bouncer, only allowing certain input.

```
this.test({mark: "Volvo", colour: "red"});
```

is a call of a test function with an object that may or may not fulfill the interface `ICar`.

The check in typescript only works on compile time, so unless you don't see errors when running the compiler via `tsc`, it could be fine.

Keep in mind that if you pass a different type during run-time, there will be no checks, and hence the code might be erroneous.